# Select unique ID while preferring column value

Tags: sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID Date  Result
1   12  good
1   11  bad
2   11  bad
2   10  bad
```

I want to get a list of unique ID's  that takes the earliest date where the result was good and if not such result exists then it takes the earliest date for said ID

The result here would be:

```
ID Date  Result
1   12  good
2   10  bad
```

I tired using Union but I keep getting duplicate ID's

Any ideas?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: use self join on your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` and `group by`:

```
select id,
       coalesce(min(case when result = 'good' then date end),
                min(date)
               )
from t
group by id;
```

EDIT:

For the value, you can use the same logic:

```
select id,
       coalesce(min(case when result = 'good' then 'good end),
                min(date)
               )
       coalesce(min(case when result = 'good' then 'good' end),
                'bad'
               )
from t
group by id;
```

This assumes that the values are either "good" or "bad".  Otherwise, you need to get the first value in the column.  The best way to do that depends on the database, which is not tagged,

Comment: OP wants the result value too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a sub-query which returns each id with its best result (good if available). JOIN with that result:

```
select t1.ID, t1.max(Date), t1.Result
from tablename t1
join (select id, max(result) result
      from tablename
      group by id) t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Result = t2.Result
group by t1.ID, t1.Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is temp.

```
with cte as (select *, row_number()over(partition by id order by result desc, date) date_rn from temp)
    select id, date, result 
    from cte c1 
    where date_rn = 1
```